# Accessing C methods from class A

Tags: java, programming-practices

```
class A {
    B bObject;
}

class B {
    private List<SomeType> list;
    public List getList() {return list;}
    public void foo(int i) {
       list.get(i).someTypeMethod(); // 2 dots
    }
}   

class SomeType {
    public void someTypeMethod() {}
}
```

Suppose I want to call `get` on the list from `bObject` in class `A`. Should I simply call `getList().get(3)`, or maybe it's better to rewrite a method in the `B` class that retrieves or adds the element at the specified position from/in the list?

In general, if class `B` field wasn't a List, but some other class `C`, should `B` prevent class `A` from calling `C` methods directly?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

You mostly want to avoid having 2 or more '.' in your methods. You try to avoid calls like 'a.b.c.d.e' which are known as [train wrecks](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TrainWreck).

Comment: its not a simple as counting '.'s though e.g. fluent interfaces are fine

Comment: @jk. I'd call the multiple '.'s a codesmell, you should think twice about your code if you're using it. For fluent API's it's fine yes.

Comment: What about the case where I have a List holding some objects in my class and have to call a method of one object from the collection? First I need to call `get(i)` and then the method - I need 2 dots for it.

Comment: If for example B has a List<Person> the 'correct way' to do it would be to add a method in B GetPerson(Id x).

Comment: No, no... I mean look at class B. If I were to call SomeType method of one of the objects from the list **in class B**, then I'd have to first retrieve the object using get and then call it

Comment: @user4205580 class `B` already knows about your `SomeType` so it's fine for `B` to access `SomeTypeMethod` via `list.get(i)`.   But If you need to write `list.get(i)` several times in `B`, then this potentially violates the DRY principle.    It would not be a bad thing to implement `SomeType Get(id)` method in class `B` - even if its a *private* method.

Comment: I always do it like Ben says.  It seems wasteful to write a new method in the sub class that simply calls list.get(index) for you, but it only takes a couple of seconds to write.  In the long run it is much simpler to avoid any kind of chained calls where you need to know about the class's internal members, especially when the class contains multiple lists and other things.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine if you don't need specific rules to control the content of the list.

if you have some specific logic to implements for adding/removing item, then you shouldn't expose the getter on the list and expose only add/remove/find/iterator methods in order to protect your list.

Another solution could be to extends an existing type of List (who said ArrayList ? :)) And override add/remove/.. method to add your logic here. So in B class you stay with the getList().